# Bypassing `blocked: mixed-content` restrictions in browsers

Tags: mixed-content

I have an internal WEB application I use, with a local printer attached.

To control the local printer (it's a ticketing printer) I use locally a small program that manages it. In order for my WEB application to "use" the printer, I make it to POST AJAX request to the small local program.

My WEB application is served with **HTTPS**, while the local program exposes a simple HTTP API through **HTTP** (non-secure).

The problem is, I am facing `blocked: mixed-content` restrictions when accessing the application through **HTTPS** (in development mode I wasn't seen this, of course).

I have several fixes (don't like any of them):

1. Make the local program to expose its simple HTTP API through **HTTPS**.

It's doable, but I will face problems with self signed certificates (will have to install them on the target machine), or will have to use **DNS** *tricks* to expose it under a "name".

2. Disallow browsers to block mixed-content

Doable. But will have to configure each browser accessing my application, plus will make them less secure.

====

So my question is: is there another way of circumventing/bypassing the `blocked: mixed-content` restriction? Ideally supported on new Firefox and Chrome versions.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't but you can upgrade all non-secure requests by allowing it in your header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```